# Any way to "bulk load" a Qt data model to avoid excess signal invocations?

Tags: qt

I have a `QStandardItemModel` with some manually implemented "select all" functionality. This loops through and updates the data for all items (or certain items—there's a filter involved). The problem is that I have some slots connected to the model's `dataChanged` signal, and I don't want them called every step of the way when the user does a "select all" and the model contains thousands of entries.

Is there any way to set multiple items all at once in the model, and have `dataChanged` emitted only once for the whole change?

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 4):

Try using the [QObject::blockSignals](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qobject.html#blockSignals) method on the object emitting the signals. This will allow you to suppress and then later restore signal generation. Very useful for exactly this type of operation.

Comment: Thanks! The only part this doesn't address is the need still to emit dataChanged signal once for the whole operation. In my particular case I have a proxy model on top of the real one, and it has an invalidate() method, but what approach would there be if I were dealing directly with the QStandardItemModel?

Comment: If you know when you have reached the last change you can unblock the signal before you perform the operation and then would get just a single signal sent.

Comment: Yeah, of course. That way just seems quite manual; it's a pity support for this sort of operation isn't built into the framework. I don't imagine it's particularly uncommon.
I'm sure I'll end up accepting this answer because it definitely was helpful and there probably isn't any better answer out there. I just feel like leaving the question open for a bit in case someone happens by with a brainwave.